# Photon list doesn't show up

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I am making a multiplayer game and I am at the MenuScene where I make the choose room - on one panel and create room - other panel . It works to create a room , but when I press to show the panel with "ChooseRoom" it doesn't appear anything. here is the script that I use.So it doesn't appear the prefab that I made with the RoomListing1(text) [image][image]
[image]

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SingletonReferences : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private MasterManager _masterManager;
}
```

```css
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RoomListingsMenu : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform _content;
    [SerializeField]
    private RoomListing _roomListing;

    private List<RoomListing> _listings = new List<RoomListing>();
    private RoomsCanvases _roomsCanvases;


    public void FirstInitialize(RoomsCanvases canvases)
    {
        _roomsCanvases = canvases;
    }

    public override void OnJoinedRoom()
    {
        _roomsCanvases.CurrentRoomCanvas.Show();
    //    _content.DestroyChildren();
        _listings.Clear();
    }

    public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
    {
        foreach (RoomInfo info in roomList)
        {
            //Removed from rooms list.
            if (info.RemovedFromList)
            {
                int index = _listings.FindIndex(x => x.RoomInfo.Name == info.Name);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    Destroy(_listings[index].gameObject);
                    _listings.RemoveAt(index);
                }
            }
            //Added to rooms list.
            else
            {
                int index = _listings.FindIndex(x => x.RoomInfo.Name == info.Name);
                if (index == -1)
                {
                    RoomListing listing = Instantiate(_roomListing, _content);
                    if (listing != null)
                    {
                        listing.SetRoomInfo(info);
                        _listings.Add(listing);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Modify listing here.
                    //_listings[index].dowhatever.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RoomListing : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text _text;

    public RoomInfo RoomInfo { get; private set; }

    public void SetRoomInfo(RoomInfo roomInfo)
    {
        RoomInfo = roomInfo;
        _text.text = roomInfo.MaxPlayers + ", " + roomInfo.Name;
    }

    public void OnClick_Button()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRoom(RoomInfo.Name);
    }

}
```

```css
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class TestConnect : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connecting to Photon...", this);
        AuthenticationValues authValues = new AuthenticationValues("0");
        PhotonNetwork.AuthValues = authValues;
        PhotonNetwork.SendRate = 20; //20.
        PhotonNetwork.SerializationRate = 5; //10.
        PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
        PhotonNetwork.NickName = MasterManager.GameSettings.NickName;
        PhotonNetwork.GameVersion = MasterManager.GameSettings.GameVersion;
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
    }

    public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected to Photon.", this);
        Debug.Log("My nickname is " + PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.NickName, this);
        if (!PhotonNetwork.InLobby)
            PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();

    }

    public override void OnDisconnected(DisconnectCause cause)
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to connect to Photon: " + cause.ToString(), this);
    }

    public override void OnJoinedLobby()
    {
        print("Joined lobby");
        PhotonNetwork.FindFriends(new string[] { "1" });
    }

    public override void OnFriendListUpdate(List<FriendInfo> friendList)
    {
        base.OnFriendListUpdate(friendList);

        foreach (FriendInfo info in friendList)
        {
            Debug.Log("Friend info received " + info.UserId + " is online? " + info.IsOnline);
        }
    }
}
```